# "Sample Frame" in Context of AudioInputStream

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am currently in the process of having to implement a codec for the Java Sound SPI. I've reached a stage where I'm going to have to change some behaviors of the [AudioInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) (thus having to override it). However, the wording of "sample frames" doesn't make any sense to me. The amount of samples and the amount of frames in my codec are very different numbers and meanings. So in context of this class, what is its meaning?

For example, frameLength is documented as "This stream's length, in sample frames." The stream's length is not equal to the amount of frames in the stream.

framePos is documented as "The current position in this stream, in sample frames (zero-based)." Does that mean it holds which frame the stream is currently on or what sample the stream is on?

Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AudioFormat docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html):

> For encodings like PCM, a frame consists of the set of samples for all channels at a given point in time, and so the size of a frame (in bytes) is always equal to the size of a sample (in bytes) times the number of channels. However, with some other sorts of encodings a frame can contain a bundle of compressed data for a whole series of samples, as well as additional, non-sample data. For such encodings, the sample rate and sample size refer to the data after it is decoded into PCM, and so they are completely different from the frame rate and frame size.

So if your codec compresses audio like e.g. mp3, a *frame* is more like a compressed chunk of data and its size has relatively little to do with sample sizes you'd encounter in uncompressed PCM encoding (more about mp3 frames can be found [here](http://www.datavoyage.com/mpgscript/mpeghdr.htm#MPEG%20HEADER)).

So `frameLength` in the `AudioInputStream` docs really just means *total number of frames in this stream*.

Or to be more clear in the context of compressed audio: *number of compressed chunks*.

When reading compressed audio, using `stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)`, a *compressed* stream is returned along with a proper `AudioFormat` instance. The user is then expected to *decompress* the stream  using something like `decompressedStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(PCM_SIGNED, stream)`.

Unfortunately, this is often misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

'sample frame' means the frame containing a single sample on all the channels. So for 8 bit mono this is 1 byte, for 16 bit stereo it is 4 bytes (2 channels, 2 bytes per sample). `AudioInputStream` gets this size from the `AudioFormat` passed to the constructor.

`frameLength` and `framePos` are then always in units of this size.

`AudioInputStream` always tries to read a complete number of sample frames so that the application code doesn't have to deal with getting part of a frame.